# validate two foreign keys in the same table referencing the same table

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, ruby-on-rails-5

I have two fields, `user_id` and `assignee_id`, in my table cards. They are both referencing a user in my table users. The presence of the first one is required, but not the second one.

In my validation, I want to check the integrity and the presence of the first, and only the integrity of the second, if filled.

I have tried that, but it doesn't work :

```
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :assignee, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => :assignee_id

  validates_presence_of [:title, :user_id]
  validates :user, presence: true
  validates :assignee_id
```

Does anyone know how to do it properly please ?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you would usually create a custom validation using [ActiveRecord::Validations#`validate`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Validations/ClassMethods/validate).

```
validates :user_id, presence: true
validate  :integrity_of_assignee_id, if: ->(obj) { obj.assignee_id.present? }

private

def integrity_of_assignee_id    
  # Add error to the field if the `assignee_id` is invalid
  errors.add(:assignee_id, 'Not valid assignee_id') unless User.find_by(id: assignee_id)
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This doesn't allow me to save an object without assignee_id, and that's not what I want. However, the integrity of the assignee_id is checked here.

Comment: @VincentDéhaye It is what I understood from your question, validate presence of `assignee_id` only if `user_id` is present. Could you explain a bit more where did I get you wrong?

Comment: assignee_id should be checked only if it is filled, its presence is not required, but user_id presence is required thus it's always filled. There's no relation between both. Is it clearer ? If yes I will edit my question :)

Comment: @VincentDéhaye or did you mean that the `assignee_id` should correspond to existent object in db? And if there is no `Assignee` with the `assignee_id` - raise exception? Le

Comment: Yes that's it, but this field is not necessarily completed.

Comment: Thank you. I tried it (just replaced Assignee.where with User.where, this is the name of my table referenced by both keys), but it still doesn't allow me to save a card without assignee, and checks the integrity of the assignee well. The return true if doesn't seem to work.

Comment: what if you remove `true`? Can you put `binding.pry` as the first line of the method and type `assignee_id` in the opened console? Is that `nil`?

Comment: The method :                       def integrity_of_assignee_id
    binding.pry
    # do nothing if field is left blank
    return  if assignee_id.blank?

                                           In the console, trying to save :NoMethodError: undefined method `pry' for #<Binding:0x00000002fc9430>

Comment: Ok, this :) `require 'pry';binding.pry`

Comment: Still in the method or at the beginning of the class the require ?

Comment: @VincentDéhaye yea, in the method, just add `require 'pry';binding.pry` as the first line instead of just `binding.pry` and see what `assignee_id` returns

Comment: My card object is named c. c.assignee_id returns nil. However I still get the same error when trying to save, even if I added the require.

Comment: @VincentDéhaye its impossible - its rails, there can not be `undefined method pry`.. Ok, remove the added line and play with `return true if assignee_id.blank?`, may be it should be `return true if c.assignee_id.blank?`, i am not sure not anymore, because I do not understand, in which model did we define this validation. But play with it, there is no chance I am wrong with this one :)

Comment: c is only the name I give to my object created in the console, the model doesn't need to take it into account. It still does the same thing, checking the integrity but requiring the field to be completed. It's weird because in the same model, I got another validation stating !completed_at.blank? and this test works. If I'm not wrong, it's the return statement which doesn't work.

Comment: @VincentDéhaye ok, i think I know how to fix it, give me 20 secs to edit the answer

Comment: @VincentDéhaye ok, check it out now

Comment: By the way, if it can help, I still have those two lines at the beginning of the class : belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :assignee, :class_name => 'User', :foreign_key => :assignee_id
       Maybe I should delete the second one ?

Comment: With this one, I can't save the object anymore, even with a good assignee_id :(

Comment: run `c.save!` (notice `!`) and tell me what's the error

Comment: ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Assignee Not valid assignee_id

Comment: @VincentDéhaye but is it because you pass invalid assignee_id or because you do not pass it at all?

Comment: None of both, the assignee_id is valid (it's 1, my first user, and I use it with success since the beginning), and it is passed, I can see it typing c, which displays the properties of my object.

Comment: @VincentDéhaye so the error is present no matter pass you assignee_id or not? That is strange..

Comment: No relation with the two belongs_to lines I mentioned ?

Comment: If I don't give it any value, it says ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Assignee must exist

Comment: THen it is 99% `null: false` in the database. Check the `schema.rb`, `assignee_id` column

Comment: @VincentDéhaye if that's db - you should remove the not null constraint and then what I showed in my answer will work.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not : t.string   "title"
    t.text     "note",         limit: 65535
    t.datetime "completed_at"
    t.datetime "due_at"
    t.integer  "user_id"
    t.integer  "assignee_id"
    t.boolean  "is_completed"
    t.datetime "created_at",                 null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                 null: false

Comment: Ok, I am sure my code is right, now it's your turn to debug step by step and see what's going on. Good luck, keep me posted, I might be of some help..

Comment: Ok thanks, I will focus on the return true statement which seem to be the problem :) I appreciate you helped me !

Comment: Ok that works, I edited your answer. I had to replace the User.where with User.find, and to delete the second belongs_to I mentioned. Apparently, you can't find implicit fields created by rails (as the user id) with a where, you need to use the find. Thanks again for your help ! Hope it will help others :)

Comment: @VincentDéhaye I rejected your edit because `find` will throw an exception if there is no such `assignee_id`, but if it works for you - just bare that in mind :)

Comment: @VincentDéhaye oh, so I would recomment to use `find_by(id: )` it will do the same as `find` but without an exception :) Try that and feel free to update my answer in any way (I'll aprove it next time, just wanted make sure you are aware of "risks") :)

Comment: @VincentDéhaye and hey, glad it finally works! Good job!

Comment: I used rescue to catch the error :) see : --- User.find(assignee_id)
  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound
    errors.add(:assignee_id, "Not valid assignee_id")
   rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid
    errors.add(:assignee_id, "Not valid assignee_id")
  end
---
I don't edit your answer because I'm not sure it's the best way, but I was aware :) glad too ! Thank you again !